# Create new item with custom title instead of ID in firebase via Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I'm doing a back end via Angular and using Firebase as DB.

It's all working great, and I've create a controller to create new pots - which works perfectly.

However, when creating a new post, it give in firebase a very long and random ID.

```
.controller("VideosCtrl", function(firebase, $scope, $firebaseArray) {

 var ref = firebase.database().ref('posts')
 $scope.groups = $firebaseArray(ref);
$scope.addgroup = function() {
$scope.groups.$add({
  title: $scope.newgroupTitle,
  caption: $scope.newgroupCaption,
  creator: $scope.newgroupCreator,
  privacy: $scope.newgroupPrivacy,
  published: $scope.newgroupPublished,

 })

}
```

I'm using scope to create the new pots, but I'd like instead of having a random ID to have the title from

```
      title: $scope.newgroupTitle,
```

so Currently My DB when I create post look like:

```
--mydomain
---- posts
------ RANDOM ID GENERATED
--------title
--------caption
--------creator
--------privacy
--------published
------ RANDOM ID GENERATED
--------title
--------caption
--------creator
--------privacy
--------published
----users
```

I'd like instead to have:

```
--mydomain
---- posts
------ TITLE ( same as below)
--------title 
--------caption
--------creator
--------privacy
--------published
------ TITLE (same as below)
--------title
--------caption
--------creator
--------privacy
--------published
----users
```

Any recommendation it will be amazing !

Thanks for your help guys !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use $add in Firebase you automatically create push id. If you want to use custom id's. Instead you should use `object.child(id).set(objectInfo);`.

I've modified your code below:

```
$scope.addgroup = function() {

  $scope.groups.$ref().child($scope.newgroupTitle).set({
    title: $scope.newgroupTitle,
    caption: $scope.newgroupCaption,
    creator: $scope.newgroupCreator,
    privacy: $scope.newgroupPrivacy,
    published: $scope.newgroupPublished
 });
}
```

This is pure javascript code but it should work since angularfire is built on top of javascript library.

One thing to note here is that it is better to use `$firebaseObject` instead of `$firebaseArray` when you want to use custom keys for storing objects in your Firebase.

Reference: [angularfire issue on github.](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/issues/672)

Comment: Thank for your time boroboris, hmm it dones't seem to do it, i have this message on the console which appear on submit:

TypeError: $scope.groups.child is not a function
    at m.$scope.addgroup

for the line   $scope.groups.child($scope.newgroupTitle).set({

Do you have any idea why ?

Comment: I've updated the answer. It seemed fishy. :) I think you need $scope.groups.$ref().child($scope.newgroupTitle).set for it to work. I haven't tested it properly though.